# Plumber problem with default parameter in post endpoint R programming

Tags: r, api, plumber

I am doing hello-world coding to learn how to use Plumber. I have written a function that takes in input 3 parameters: n=Number of observations, min=Lower limit of the distribution and max=Upper limit of the distribution. Must be finite. The default value of min is 0 and the default value of max is 1.

```
library(plumber)

#* @apiTitle Plumber Example API
#* @apiDescription Plumber example description.

#* Return Random numbers from a uniform distribution
#* @param n Number of observations. If length(n) > 1, the length is taken to be the number required.
#* @param min Lower limit of the distribution. Must be finite. Default is 0.
#* @param max Upper limit of the distribution. Must be finite. Default is 1.
#* @post /random-uniform-distribution 
function(n, min=0, max=1){
  runif(as.numeric(n), as.numeric(min), as.numeric(max))
}
```

However, as you can see in the next figure, only min is considered as default, while max has a value of 1. This value is also present in the Request URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/random-uniform-distribution?n=3&max=1
```

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? Are you construction this request URL yourself? What is the behavior that you are expecting?

Comment: Thanks for help. My question is very simple and I apologize. Why is it that even though min and max are defaults they have different behavior?

Comment: What behaviors are you taking about specifically? I'm not sure I understand. Is this a question about how things appear in the swagger UI to actually test your endpoints? Or are you trying to actually access the API endpoints from some other application and are having a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have written an API where two parameters are default (min and max). However on the UI swagger (as seen in the picture) and on the Request URL (as seen in the code line) the behavior of Min and Max are different (even though they are both defaults) and only min seems to default.

Comment: I think that may be a problem with the preview and the default values it chooses. If you remove the auto-filled "1" value from the max, it still works. The API endpoint itself seems to be working fine. The documentation that opens when you run the app is just to help with testing. plumber uses this tool: https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/. Perhaps you could file a issue with them.